# How to use multi-index for better performance in mysql also into python

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pymysql

I have a table in MySQL that consists of more than 400 million rows. It looks something like this:

```
device    date       type .....
  A     2019-06-16    1
  A1    2019-06-20    2 
  A2    2019-10-16    3
  B     2019-06-16    3
```

Currently when I run show index query it outputs:

```
Table         Non_unique     key_name       seq_in_index    col_name   Collation    Cardinality   Index_type
device_table      1      table_device_date      1             device       A           6444       BTREE
device_table      1      table_device_date      2             date         A           418571     BTREE
```

Since my data is too large, I want to call day by day in python then append each days. (Calling month of data in python is not working, and I do not want to scale up).

so I want to call one day worth of data in most efficient way.

```
Explain select * from device_table
where date between DATE('2019-10-01') AND DATE('2019-10-02');
```

which outputs

```
Id    select_type table         type       rows      Extra
1         simple  device_table   All       400mil   Using Where
```

I have index on date column, why is it not using it in the above query?

Also what does seq_in_index mean in show index query?

Thanks.

EDIT:
 Thanks to EdmCoff, Akina.

From their help, if I've understood correctly. Since my table's indexing is in order of [device, date] I cannot go straight and look for [date] so in order to leverage date index, need to do it through device.

so to do that, I do something like

```
select * from device_table
where 
  device = 'A' and
  date between DATE('2019-10-01') and DATE('2019-10-02');
```

and It seems to work perfectly.

Only now, I have about 7000 different device and need to get date from 2019-10-01 ~ 2019-12-01.

My approach right now is by using python (using pymysql),

```
date_range = pd.date_range(start='2019-10-01', end='2019-10-10', freq='1d').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

for device_id in device_list:
    for i in range(1, len(date_range)):
        query = f"""
        select * from device_table
        where
          device = '{device_id}' and
          date between DATE('{date_range[i-1]}') and DATE('{date_range[i]}');
        """

        df = pd.read_sql(query, con=conn)

        final_df.append(df, sort=False, ignore_index=True)
```

Note: device_list = ['A', "B", ....etc]

Would there be another way either by changing indexing or other?

Comment: Date is the second column in your index. The index `device,date` will improve performance when querying with a device _and_ date condition, or just a device condition. But it can't be used only for date. (If you imagine a paper index sorted by device and then date, it would not be easy for you look something up by date.)

Comment: Even though I only want date condition I must use `device, date` ? How would I use that in a query?

Comment: No, sorry. I mean the index you have defined is not appropriate for your query. It will only help when querying device. You should add an index on date (or, if this is the only type of query you run on this table, you could replace your current index).

Comment: Then why is `date` shown when I run show index query?

Comment: Because you have date as part of the index, but it is not the _first_ part. Imagine a paper index that you are reading with your eyes sorted by last name then first name... You can quickly get to the correct last name section and then the correct first name section, but it doesn't help you if you're starting with the first name.

Comment: So that is what Seq_in_index is referring to?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: so right now best I can do is index by [device, date] which would take me to one device id then go around all dates, another device then go around all dates and so on?

Comment: If you want to use that index, then yes. But more generally, it sounds like you should add another index or reorder that index (depending on what your other queries need).

Comment: So in my case using index [device, date] would be better right? but how can I do that? `select * from table where ???` ?

Comment: Create index by `(date)` only or as a prefix of index expression (for example, by `(date, device)`). Use `WHERE date IN ('2019-10-01', '2019-10-02')` instead of between. Until the amount of values to check is below ~50-70 the index must be used. If not then test does the index forcing will increase your query performance. If true then renew table's statistic. And replace the asterisk with the fieldnames which you really need in.

Comment: *So in my case using index [device, date] would be better right?* Your index is applicable to the queries with WHERE clause like `WHERE device [=value | IN (valueslist)] [AND date [=value | IN (valueslist) | BETWEEN date_from AND date_till]] [AND (another conditions)]`.